# Set up a Fax server to filter spam

Tags: spam, fax, filter, block

At my work, we have a huge costly multi-function printer that does everything a printer can dream of. It is hooked up directly on a dedicated fax telephone line. Now we receive an increasing amount of unsolicited fax mail. We are in Canada, there are no regulations about these so we can't simply hope that the governement shuts them down.

What would be the best solution to block these incoming faxes? The first idea was to setup a filter box to handle traffic but I'd like to have experts opinion before starting to spend money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know of a good solution. I'm in the US, I've always seen a small pile of junk faxes next to any machine that allows inbound.

Thoughts:

1. Do you have a business need for inbound faxing? If not, turn it off.
2. Related to the above - can you turn it off overnight? Don't know if this will do much to cut down the volume.
3. Can you have the faxes go to an email box or image archive instead of direct to paper? Then you can have admin staff go through them.

Comment: I'm currently looking at point 3, not sure about how to do this however. We have a Xerox Phaser 8560

Comment: Looks like you have the 8560MFP, to be specific.  Page 6-21 tells you how to enable Junk Fax prevention. And 6-18 tells you how to enable Secure Fax, which requires a PIN before printing a fax, which can be done at the panel or in their management server software, Centreware. http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/docs/8510MFP/userdocs/any-os/en/user_guide_en.pdf